# Unit testing the code that is written using repository pattern

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am implemented my business logic using repository pattern. I basically have Approve method in my controller . I am calling the service method ApproveUserChangeRequest
which in turn invokes GetUserChangeRequest and ApproveUserChangeRequest in the UnitofWork class. I would like to know if this is standard or better way of doing it
Please bare in mind in to test the service methods

UserConroller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("approve-change-request")]
public IActionResult ApproveUserChangeRequest([FromBody] ApproveUserChangeRequests approveUserChangeRequests)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(new ResponseModel()
        {
            ResponseMessages = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
            {
                { "Errors", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray() }
            }
        });
    }    

    var result  = _userService.ApproveUserChangeRequest(approveUserChangeRequests);
    var message = string.Empty;
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Ok(new ResponseModel()
        {
            ResponseMessages = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
            {
               { "Info", new string[] { $"True" } }
            }
        });
    }
    message = string.Join(";", result.Errors.Select(x => $"Code: {x.Code}. Description: {x.Description}"));
    _logger.Error(new IdentityException($"Error approving user change requests. Message: {message}"));
    return BadRequest();

}
```

UserService class

```
public  IdentityResult ApproveUserChangeRequest(ApproveUserChangeRequests approveUserChangeRequests)
{
    var userChangeRequest = _userUow.GetUserChangeRequest(approveUserChangeRequests.UserChangeRequestID);

    IdentityResult result =  _userUow.ApproveUserChangeRequest(userChangeRequest, approveUserChangeRequests.ApprovedByAuthUserId, approveUserChangeRequests.AuthApplicationName);
    return result;
}
```

UnitofWork class (uow)

```
public UserChangeRequest GetUserChangeRequest(int userChangeRequestId)
{
    return UserChangeRequestRepository.GetQueryable(x =>
        x.Id == userChangeRequestId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}


public IdentityResult ApproveUserChangeRequest(UserChangeRequest userChangeRequest, int approvedByAuthUserId, string authApplicationName)
{
    var idResult = IdentityResult.Success;

    // Check if UserChangeRequest is still Pending
    bool isUserChangeRequestPending = UserChangeRequestRepository.GetQueryable(x => x.Id == userChangeRequest.Id && x.ChangeStatus == "Pending").Any();

    if (isUserChangeRequestPending && approvedByAuthUserId > 0)
    {
        // Inserting record in the UserChangeRequestApproval table
        InsertUserChangeRequestApproval(userChangeRequest);
        SaveContext();

        //Updating the user details in IdentityDB, ClientCompanyContact and AuthUser tables 
        UpdateUserDetails(userChangeRequest, authApplicationName);
    }
    else
    {
        idResult = IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError { Description = "No userchange request to approve" });
    }
    return idResult;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like this may be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's important to only test each part of your application in isolation. When we test `public IActionResult ApproveUserChangeRequest` we only want to ensure that it's doing its own job correctly.  Anything that it calls should be mocked, and tested separately.

For this you will need to create interfaces for your repository, and your UnitOfWork class.  This will allow them to be mocked, and their behaviour simulated.

You should also allow these classes to be injected into the consuming class using Dependency Injection, for example:

```
private readonly IUserService _userService;

public MyController(IUserService userService)
{
    _userService = userService;
}

public IActionResult ApproveUserChangeRequest([FromBody] ApproveUserChangeRequests approveUserChangeRequests)
{
    // ... snip
    // this now uses the instance that was provided by dependency injection
    var result = _userService.ApproveUserChangeRequest(approveUserChangeRequests);
}
```

You would then be able to test your class/method, whilst mocking the behaviour of your user service.  The following example uses Moq, but you could use another mocking framework.

```
public void ApproveUserChangeRequest_PassesApproveChangeRequestsModelToService()
{
    // mock the user service
    var userService = new Mock<IUserService>();
    // provide the controller with the user service
    var controller = new MyController(userService);
    // create the model for the request
    var model = new ApproveUserChangeRequests();
    // test the method
    controller.ApproveUserChangeRequest(model);

    // make sure that userService.ApproveUserChangeRequest was called with the correct arguments
    userService.Verify(u => u.ApproveUserChangeRequest(model));
}
```

In the unit tests for the Controller, you only need to check that ApproveUserChangeRequest is doing it's job correctly.  That is

- verifying your model
- raising an error if the model isn't valid
- calling the user service if it is valid
- sending you the correct response if it's successful
- logging correctly to your logger
- responding with bad request if appropriate

These should all be checked for in separate unit tests.

You should also then write tests for your UserService, and your UnitOfWork class.  Only write tests for things that those classes are responsible for.  If you find that the class is responsible for too many things, refactor your class until it obeys the single responsibility principle, this will greatly aid your ability to test your code.